# Time not configuring correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, time, timeslider

I'm trying to match data in a textfile that contains time, value, and fips code to the cntyidfp part of a map of US counties. However, even though I am able to match the two sets of data together, ArcGIS does not recognize I have multiple dates. It either says the date values are from 01/01/0001 (which isn't even close to correct), or that the only date that exists is 01/01/1999. The date range is one week, and I want to create an animation by the hour. Is there an error in how my data is saved or something? This is what the textfile generally looks like :

```
string_datetime,load,fips
"01/01/1999 0:00:00",14769,"01001"
"01/01/1999 1:00:00",14634,"01001"
"01/01/1999 2:00:00",14481,"01001"
"01/01/1999 3:00:00",14635,"01001"
"01/01/1999 4:00:00",14617,"01001"
"01/01/1999 5:00:00",15225,"01001"
"01/01/1999 6:00:00",15567,"01001"
"01/01/1999 7:00:00",15720,"01001"
"01/01/1999 8:00:00",15864,"01001"
"01/01/1999 9:00:00",15856,"01001"
"01/01/1999 10:00:00",15666,"01001"
"01/01/1999 11:00:00",15267,"01001"
"01/01/1999 12:00:00",14759,"01001"
"01/01/1999 13:00:00",14302,"01001"
"01/01/1999 14:00:00",13974,"01001"
"01/01/1999 15:00:00",13925,"01001"
"01/01/1999 16:00:00",14362,"01001"
"01/01/1999 17:00:00",15504,"01001"
"01/01/1999 18:00:00",15707,"01001"
"01/01/1999 19:00:00",15498,"01001"
"01/01/1999 20:00:00",15214,"01001"
"01/01/1999 21:00:00",14944,"01001"
"01/01/1999 22:00:00",14354,"01001"
"01/01/1999 23:00:00",13535,"01001"
"01/02/1999 0:00:00",13033,"01001"
"01/02/1999 1:00:00",12776,"01001"
"01/02/1999 2:00:00",12648,"01001"
"01/02/1999 3:00:00",12687,"01001"
.
.
.
.
"01/07/1999 18:00:00",7229,"56039"
"01/07/1999 19:00:00",7118,"56039"
"01/07/1999 20:00:00",6752,"56039"
"01/07/1999 21:00:00",6467,"56039"
"01/07/1999 22:00:00",6114,"56039"
"01/07/1999 23:00:00",5594,"56039"
```

I have also tried resaving the dates in various formats, including without quotes, or in a 1999-01-01 fashion. Thus far, however, nothing seems to work. Where am I potentially going wrong? The county map is the standard shapefile from the tiger website.

Comment: I should also note that if time is enabled only on the textfile, all dates are recognized, while if it is enabled on the joined textfile-county map, they are not.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out the explanation, in case anyone else runs into the issue: work 100% within a geodatabase. Was a rookie mistake.